# Expectation of Maximum Frequency

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, expectation, puzzle

**I saw this question in a blog but do not know how to solve it.**

**Question:** There are K balls in a sack numbered 1 to K. Bob chooses a ball at random and notes down its number and then puts it back in sack. He does this process for N times. What is the expected value of the frequency of the most frequent element?

Comment: I had expected to see a closed form solution by now. Will an algorithm do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a solution, but it's too long for a comment. Also, for reasons stated below, I think you are unlikely to get a closed form solution.

This problem is equivalent to finding the expected length of the longest chain in a hash table.  As such, it appears the problem has been extensively studied, yet no one has found a closed form solution.  The best result seems to be that if $N, K \to \infty$ in such a way that $N/K = \alpha$ with $\alpha$ constant, then the average maximum occupancy (i.e., the frequency of the most frequent element, in your formulation of the problem) is asymptotic to $\ln N / \ln \ln N$.

Reference: Section 9.4 in *An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms, Second Edition* by Robert Sedgewick and Philippe Flajolet.  The original paper appears to be by G. H. Gonnet, "Expected length of the longest probe sequence in hash code searching," *Journal of the ACM* **28**, 1981, 289-309.